# Bind Linq to Datagridtextcolumn

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to add values to my DatagridTextcolumn from a Linq query.

What I have tried:

```
DataGridTextColumn test = new DataGridTextColumn();
test.Binding = new Binding("test");
dgServer.Columns.Add(test);

dgServer.Items.Add(new Person()
{
  Status = Convert.ToBoolean(from a in db.Persons
          from d in db.PersonDetails
          where a.pID == d.pDID && a.State == "Active" 
          select a)
});
```

XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="test" Binding="{Binding}" Header="test"/>
```

I have an exception for the above code, saying

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1 to type 'System.IConvertible'.

how to bind to a `DatagridTextcolumn` binding from LINQ to SQL.

Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic code -

```
Status = Convert.ToBoolean(from a in db.Persons
          from d in db.PersonDetails
          where a.pID == d.pDID && a.State == "Active" 
          select a)
```

The query inside will return `IEnumerable of type Person` and you are trying to convert this to `Boolean` which obviously won't compile since there is no `implicit conversion` from `IEnumerable<Person>` to `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are trying to convert a linq query rather than the results of that query.  The issue arises from Linq's deferred execution model.  Try adding a 'FirstOrDefault()' method to the parameter of your ToBoolean call:

```
Status = Convert.ToBoolean((from a in db.Persons
      from d in db.PersonDetails
      where a.pID == d.pDID && a.State == "Active" 
      select a).FirstOrDefault())
```

Rohit also has a good point - you need to make sure than you can actually convert from type Person to Boolean

Comment: thanks for the update, but how to bind this to DatagridTextcolumn binding property ?

Comment: @Buba1947 With this answer in mind it would be `<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="test" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="test"/>`, so you forgot the path.